# What is evaluation plan for heap table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a question from a test I took several days ago:

> Describe a query evaluation plan for the query
>
> ```
> SELECT * from Student where login='kra2286'
> ```
>
> for the heap table and the index created for the login attribute

At first I thought the question ask me to describe in detail what would happen inside the database if we run the query `SELECT * from Student where login='kra2286'`, so I wrote:

> The database will search for value 'kra2286' from login attribute in the Student table, and if it found one, it will display every value of every attribute of that value.

But that was an incorrect answer. I asked my professor about the question, but he suggested I study about "Physical Database Design, Query Processing" in database. I did read his lecture multiple times, but still, I cannot find the answer for his question.

What is the correct way to answer this kind of question?

Comment: Tables have columns, not attributes. I guess your professor is the only one who knows what answer was expected

Comment: It's not so obvious that index is unique, so we can find none, one or more than one row. Also phrase "every value of every attribute of that value" is unfortunate. Every atturibute of a founded record(s) is more descriptive.

Comment: @Kadet also, tables have rows, not records

Comment: @HoneyBadger hard to say, in many sources rows of table are called records sometimes even tuple. But row is maybe the best answer here (because we use i.e. row_number). If it's academic question then answer , or naming convention that should be used, is in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct about what the database will do, but when the question asks for a "query evaluation plan" it's asking for more detail about **how** it will do it; just "search the table" is much too vague.

The question is probably wanting you to talk about things like whether there is an index on the column to do an "index seek" vs "table scan", and maybe even talk about loading pages from disk to memory, though that latter seems more involved than I'd expect from a college course.